# GIMP scripting: can a batch process be interactive?

Tags: gimp, script-fu, python-fu

I have a folder of images from which I need to make 60x60pixel thumbnails. The originals are of mixed sizes, and I'd like to be able to select which portion of each image to use for the thumbnail. Is there a way to automate this with Gimp scripting?

I imagine the sequence to be as follows:

```
1. Wait for user to specify source folder.
2. Open first image.
3. Wait for user to select part of the image
   (with fixed 1:1 aspect ratio)
   (... how does the user tell the script to continue?)
4. Crop to selection.
5. Resize image to 60x60.
6. Apply sharpen filter (some fixed settings for this are ok).
7. Save image.
8. Open next image (if any) and repeat from step 3 above.
```

Ideally, everything except steps 1 & 3 would be automated. Is this possible? If so, some tips on how to get started would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: um, hello? anyone? guess this is the kind of question the `tumbleweed` badge is designed for...

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question. If you are still interested in solving it, I could have a go at it.

Comment: @Marwan thanks, but I worked it out using a python image library in the end, not Gimp.

Comment: Good to hear, when I saw the tumbleweed comment I thought I'd try and come to the rescue :)

Comment: I’m sure that you could use `pygtk` to create a window with a “Continue” button for the user to press at the end of step 3.